# Firebase: User does not have permissions to access this object

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm having a problem pulling images from **Firebase Storage**. I get the error message:

> com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: User does not have permission to access this object.

I have changed the permissions in firebase to all of the following and none of them work.

1.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/wics-application.appspot.com/o {
    match /public/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
    match /user/{allPaths=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
    match /auth/{allPaths=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

2.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/wics-application.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any other reason that I could be getting this message?

Comment: Is the user authenticated or not? Show your relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an instance of FirebaseUser?

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseUser mUser;
```

Above onCreate and in onCreate

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

Then call your storage